# Wrong number of arguments to IFERROR. Expected between 1 and 2 arguments, but got 3 arguments

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to make this formula work but I keep getting this error 'Wrong number of arguments to IFERROR. Expected between 1 and 2 arguments, but got 3 arguments.'

Any Ideas?

`=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B7,Accepted!D3:DD984,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B7,Completed!D3:D1014,1,FALSE),"Not Sold")=B7,"Sold","Not Sold")`

Trying to look up for a name in two separate tables to see if its sold or not.

Comment: Sorted myself, I have missed on IFERROR...

=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B6,Accepted!D2:DD983,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B6,Completed!D2:D1013,1,FALSE))=B6,"Sold","Not Sold")

Answer (score 0):

*You may also try:*

```js
=if(len(B7),ifs(
    ifna(vlookup(B7,Accepted!D3:D,1,))=B7,"Not Sold",
    ifna(vlookup(B7,Completed!D3:D,1,))=B7,"Sold",
    1,"Match not found"
    ),)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also count how many times the name appears:

```cpp
=IF(2=COUNTIF({Accepted!D3:D;Completed!D3:D},B7),"Sold","Not sold")
```

Or, if a name may appear more than once in the same list:

```cpp
=IF(COUNTIF(Accepted!D3:D,B7)*COUNTIF(Completed!D3:D,B7),"Sold","Not sold")
```